# Gridstack.js Delete Widget using Jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

Below is the Jquery Function I am using I have no idea how to use remove_widget please help:
I am not able to find any help on deleting widget whereas the Knockout.js is not of my use as I am not using it.

```
$(function () {
var options = {resizable: {
handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w'
}
};

$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);

        new function () {
            this.serialized_data = [
                {x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2},
                {x: 3, y: 1, width: 1, height: 2},
                {x: 4, y: 1, width: 1, height: 1},
                {x: 2, y: 3, width: 3, height: 1},
                {x: 1, y: 4, width: 1, height: 1},
                {x: 1, y: 3, width: 1, height: 1},
                {x: 2, y: 4, width: 1, height: 1},
                {x: 2, y: 5, width: 1, height: 1}
            ];

            this.grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');

            this.load_grid = function () {
                this.grid.remove_all();
                var items = GridStackUI.Utils.sort(this.serialized_data);
                _.each(items, function (node) {
                    this.grid.add_widget($('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content" /><div/>'),
                        node.x, node.y, node.width, node.height);
                }, this);
            }.bind(this);

            this.save_grid = function () {
                this.serialized_data = _.map($('.grid-stack > .grid-stack-item:visible'), function (el) {
                    el = $(el);
                    var node = el.data('_gridstack_node');
                    return {
                        x: node.x,
                        y: node.y,
                        width: node.width,
                        height: node.height
                    };
                }, this);
                $('#saved-data').val(JSON.stringify(this.serialized_data, null, '    '));
            }.bind(this);

            this.clear_grid = function () {
                this.grid.remove_all();
            }.bind(this);
            this.add_grid = function(){
                this.grid.add_widget($('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content" /><i class=" fa fa-remove"></><div/>'), 0, 0, 3, 2, true);
                $('.fa-remove').click(this.remove_grid);
            }.bind(this);
            this.remove_grid = function(){
                this.grid.remove_widget("What should I use Here", true);
            }.bind(this);
            $('#save-grid').click(this.save_grid);
            $('#load-grid').click(this.load_grid);
            $('#clear-grid').click(this.clear_grid);
            $('#add-grid').click(this.add_grid);
            $('.fa-remove').click($(this).remove_grid);
            this.load_grid();
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you dynamically add items;
Also assuming you have a triggering element with a class 'remove';

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack'),
        el = $(this).closest('.grid-stack-item')

    grid.remove_widget(el);
});
```

note: narrow down your context to the actual container and reference it instead of $('body')

> Function `remove_widget` is deprecated as of v0.2.5 and has been
>   replaced with `removeWidget`. It will be **completely** removed in
>   v1.0.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd share my approach, which may might help someone.

```
var $eGridstack = $(".grid-stack");

$(".btn-delete").click(function ()
{
    let $widget = $(this).closest(".grid-stack-item");

    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this widget?") == true)
    { 
        $eGridstack.data('gridstack').removeWidget($widget);
    }
}
```

**Note `remove_widget` has been deprecated.**

> Function `remove_widget` is deprecated as of v0.2.5 and has been replaced with `removeWidget`. It will be **completely** removed in v1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Removing widget after click checkbox

```
$("#mycheckbox").click(function () {if (document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked == false)
                    { 
                        $("#myblockContent").insertAfter("#spantrash");
                        var grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');
                        el=$('#divGridstackContent').closest('.grid-stack-item');
                        grid.removeWidget(el);
                    }
                    else{
                        var grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');
                        grid.addWidget($('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content divscroll" id="divGridstackContent" ><span id="spanContent"></span></div></div>'), {id: "Content", x: "0", y: "6", width: "6", height: "6"});
                        $( "#blockContent" ).insertAfter( "#spanContent" );

                    }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gridstackjs.com/demo/serialization.html

if you still have a problem, use:

```
grid.removeWidget(this.parentNode.parentNode);
```